# will running ubuntu from a live usb key affect my windows 10 installation in any way?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, live-usb

I have made a live installation of ubuntu to a usb key using the provided usb universal installer and selected an amount of persistant hard drive space on the key. What I want to know is, will booting from and using the usb key ubuntu OS in anyway way, shape or form touch, affect, write to or modify my internal hard drive with windows 10 sitting on it?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: @DavidFoerster The OP seems to be asking if running the LiveCD causes any unexpected modifications to Windows partitions whereas the other question is asking whether intentional changes to the Windows partition are persistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you're purely using the persistent storage on the USB key there will be no adverse effects to your windows system, it's completely separate, and you're only using resources such as the CPU and memory from the machine, not the HDD with the Windows OS installed.

**However** if you mount the HDD which contains Windows, and make any changes to the filesystem, this can affect the files on that disk, including files which are necessary for Windows to operate.

If you don't play around with anything on the internal HDD, you will be fine.